# Why the "CASE WHEN" condition is not working properly in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've just written this simple code, and there's this small issue that I'm facing.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN ReferenceTableName IS NULL AND TemplateTableName IS NOT NULL 
          THEN '(SELECT ' + TemplateColumnName + ' FROM [Template].[dbo].[' + TemplateTableName + ']) AS [' + VerticalColumnName + ']'
       WHEN ReferenceTableName IS NOT NULL AND TemplateTableName IS NULL 
          THEN '(SELECT ' + ReferenceColumnName + ' FROM ' + ReferenceTableName + ' WHERE Mjolnir_Source_ID = ' + ' ) AS [' + VerticalColumnName + ']'
       ELSE DefaultValue + ' AS [' + VerticalColumnName + ']'  
    END
FROM
    Reference..TemplateMappingExceptions 
WHERE 
    VerticalTableName = 'TRSMemberships'
```

So the result that I'm getting form this code is shown below and is not using the `NULL AS VerticalcolumnName` for the row where `DefaultValue` column value is NULL.

```
 GetDate() AS [FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart]
 GetDate() AS [FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart]
 '1753-01-01' AS [LastLockedOutDate]
 '1753-01-01' AS [LastPasswordChangedDate]
 GetDate() AS [LastActivityDate]
 GetDate() AS [LastLoginDate]
 GetDate() AS [CreateDate]
 (SELECT Name FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [UserName]
 (SELECT Email FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [Email]
 (SELECT LOWER(Email) FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [LoweredEmail]
 NULL
 NULL
 NULL
 (SELECT isLockedOut FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [isLockedOut]
 1 AS [isApproved]
 NULL
 NULL
 0 AS [ForceChangePassword]
 (SELECT Unit4ID FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [Unit4ID]
 NULL
 NULL
 NULL
 NULL
 (SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Mjolnir_Source_ID =  ) AS [UserID]
```

The desired result should look like this,

```
 GetDate() AS [FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart]
 GetDate() AS [FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart]
 '1753-01-01' AS [LastLockedOutDate]
 '1753-01-01' AS [LastPasswordChangedDate]
 GetDate() AS [LastActivityDate]
 GetDate() AS [LastLoginDate]
 GetDate() AS [CreateDate]
 (SELECT Name FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [UserName]
 (SELECT Email FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [Email]
 (SELECT LOWER(Email) FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [LoweredEmail]
 NULL AS [FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount]
 NULL AS [FailedPasswordAttemptCount]
 NULL AS [Comment]
 (SELECT isLockedOut FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [isLockedOut]
 1 AS [isApproved]
 NULL AS [PasswordEncryptionType]
 NULL AS [AnswerEncryptionType]
 0 AS [ForceChangePassword]
 (SELECT Unit4ID FROM [Template].[dbo].[UserStructure_Users]) AS [Unit4ID]
 NULL AS [PasswordQuestion]
 NULL AS [PasswordAnswer]
 NULL AS [PasswordSalt]
 NULL AS [Password]
 (SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Mjolnir_Source_ID =  ) AS [UserID]
```

Comment: FYI, `N'[' + TemplateTableName + N']'` is *not* injection safe. If you are injection object names, then *always* use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: @Larnu will keep in mind next time. Thanks

Comment: @Larnu any insight about where i'm making the mistake?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying here, if I am honest. The `CASE` expression returns what ever value is related to the `WHEN` that returns true; that's how they work. Sample data, expected results, or a [mre] will help us help you.

Comment: Obviously, if `DefaultValue` is `NULL` any concatenation with it results in `NULL`; presumably you want `ISNULL(DefaultValue, 'NULL')`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. Learnt a new thing today. @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the result of something unknown (NULL) with anything else is still unknown.

you need to convert null values to string 'null' :

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN ReferenceTableName IS NULL AND TemplateTableName IS NOT NULL 
          THEN '(SELECT ' + TemplateColumnName + ' FROM [Template].[dbo].[' + TemplateTableName + ']) AS [' + VerticalColumnName + ']'
       WHEN ReferenceTableName IS NOT NULL AND TemplateTableName IS NULL 
          THEN '(SELECT ' + ReferenceColumnName + ' FROM ' + ReferenceTableName + ' WHERE Mjolnir_Source_ID = ' + ' ) AS [' + VerticalColumnName + ']'
       ELSE ISNULL(DefaultValue,'NULL') + ' AS [' + VerticalColumnName + ']'  
    END
FROM
    Reference..TemplateMappingExceptions 
WHERE 
    VerticalTableName = 'TRSMemberships'
```